# In OpenIdConnect getUser returns null, even after the receiving token

Tags: aurelia, openid-connect

After being successfully authenticated by the Identity Server, a token is returned and the user is redirected to `app.ts`. However, when I call `getUser()` in `app.ts` it returns `null`. This code is working properly in localhost, but when I try it in production it doesn't work (returns `null`).

app.ts

```
constructor(private openIdConnect: OpenIdConnect, private httpClient: HttpClient) {
    debugger;
    let mgr = this.openIdConnect.userManager;
    this.openIdConnect.userManager.getUser().then((user) => {
      if (user) {
        this.user = user;
        console.log(" This.User: "+this.user);
        console.log(" User: "+ user)      
      }else{
        console.log(" logout ");
         this.logout();
      }
    });
  }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Problem was the way I build the app to production.So earlier I used "`au build --env prod` " I change it to “`au build --env`”